# I want a logged in user to see only its saved information

Tags: python, django

I just started learning django. i created a model and i expect when a user logs in, the user should see only info it saved but when another user logs in, it sees saved information from other users

view.py

```
def user_locker(request):
    saved_info = Locker.objects.all()
    all_saved_info = {'saved_info': saved_info}
    return render(request, 'pwdbank/user_locker.html', all_saved_info)
```

model.py

```
class Locker(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    site_url = models.URLField(max_length=55)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.site_name}'
```

Thank you. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the `request` to be allowed only for logged in users.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def user_locker(request):
    saved_info = Locker.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    all_saved_info = {'saved_info': saved_info}
    return render(request, 'pwdbank/user_locker.html', all_saved_info)
```

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator